# Observable.using not working in Rxjava 1.1.6

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have below code

```
 public static Observable<Void> usingProgressDialog(final Context context) {
    return Observable.using(
            () -> {
                ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
                progressDialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.loading));
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
                return progressDialog;
            },
            progressDialog -> Observable.just(null), Dialog::dismiss);
}
```

It worked in Rxjava 1.1.5 But in Rxjava 1.1.6 not working

I find the problem. But I do not figure out how to fix. Please. Help me!

[RxJava pull #3922](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/pull/3922)

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Compilation error? Runtime problem?

Comment: It not show dialog.

Comment: I import version 1.1.5 , It have show dialog. But I import version: 1.1.6. It not working :(

Answer (score 0):

See the android monitor to ensure the package is imported and also you update necessary files, if everything is fine it should work. In order to double check revert it back to 1.1.5 and see is it working if it not then error might be in code not in Rxjava, no one could help you until you give details in Android  monitor this type of error mainly arise due to development environment in most case.

Comment: I sure it error in rxjava 1.1.6. because. I import  compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.5', it worked. but I import compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'. it not working :(

Comment: Have you looked in to gradle file and have you changed the compile out there to 1.1.6.

Comment: Yes. I have changed the compile to 1.1.6. Please. View https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4144

Comment: When I looked in to the issue it seems to be bug in version 1.1.6 and in one of the place it clearly mentioned if you call disposeEagerly == false make it true, hope the problem should be resolved.